# Forcing a reload in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webbrowser-control, lavalamp

I am making use of the Lavalamp plugin from http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/ and everything seems to be working fine except that there is a little quirk when using the back button.

For example:

1. If you are starting off from the home page, the hover is underneath the home menu.
2. Click on a new menu item, the hover appears underneath it
3. Click on the browser's back button, and the hover does not return to the home menu item, it stays at the previously clicked one.

I need to find a way to call the Lavalamp function when the back button is being triggered.

Hope to get some help here

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the [OnBeforeUnload](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/825556-using-onbeforeunload-javascript-event) event is what you are looking for.

Comment: i don't think the OnBeforeUnload event is what I am looking for, it doesn't quite fit in actually